# Seaborn tsplot - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape tsplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

I am trying to use seaborn's tsplot (sns.tsplot) as I want to show the variation in values of a series for the different months over 5 years (as well as the mean).
I have attached an image of my dataframe. This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.tsplot(data = df_monthly, time = 'month', value = 'pm_local',      unit="dayofweek");

plt.show()
```

I cannot work out why I receive the following error message since the index just goes from 0 onwards:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Any suggestions of why this might be and how I can get the tsplot working?

Comment: I don't think the variable that is used for the `time` parameter can be duplicated. Use the `date` column instead.

Comment: I just tried that now, and it plots something atleast, but the I really want the month along the x axis. I thought the time parameter can be duplicated, so it the values in 'value' can be used to create the shaded area above and below the mean

Comment: Please don't post an image but rather a sample of your dataframe that we can copy and import in pandas (or a sample of code that will create the dataframe)

Comment: @paulos please post a sample dataframe with at least 24 months of data